# POSIX FIFO freezes when opened in blocking mode

Tags: c, linux, posix, named-pipes, fifo

By default a POSIX FIFO is opened in blocking mode.  My problem is that when I open it in blocking mode it just freezes (blocks) and nothing else happens.

Originally I opened both sides with the RDWR flag and I had no problems because RDWR makes it nonblocking because "Under Linux, opening a FIFO for read and write will succeed both in blocking and nonblocking mode" (https://linux.die.net/man/7/fifo).  But in nonblocking mode I sometimes get dropped records, so I need to open it in blocking mode.

Here's how I call mkfifo:

```
int64_t fifo_setup(char * fifo_name)
{
    if (mkfifo(fifo_name, S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH) == -1) {
        perror("mkfifo");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

   return 0; }
```

My original call to open:

```
int64_t fifo_open(char * fifo_name, int64_t read_write) {

    int c;

    if (read_write == 1) { 
        c = open(fifo_name, O_RDWR);}
    if (read_write == 2) { 
        c = open(fifo_name, O_RDWR);}

    perror("open");

    return (c);
}
```

Then I changed it to:

```
int64_t fifo_open(char * fifo_name, int64_t read_write) {

    int c;

    if (read_write == 1) { 
        c = open(fifo_name, O_WRONLY);}
    if (read_write == 2) { 
        c = open(fifo_name, O_RDONLY);}

    perror("open");

    return (c);
}
```

My program reaches the open call for the writer threads (this is a NASM call to C):

```
Open_FIFO_Write:
lea rdi,[fifo_name]
mov rsi,1
call fifo_open wrt ..plt
mov [fifo_write_fd],rax
```

But then the Putty terminal freezes (blocks) and nothing else happens.  I never get to the block that opens the reading side.  Specifically it blocks just before it reaches perror("open") in the fifo_open code above:

According to the Linux man page at https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html, "Normally, opening the FIFO blocks until the other end is opened also."  That's great but I can't get to the code that opens the writer because the reader blocks all further progress.  It's like a Mexican standoff.

Of course there must be a way but my research hasn't found it yet.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Are you trying to open both ends of the pipe in a single process? Why? Why use a pipe inside one single process? And if you intend to pass it on to a child-process that you `fork`, why use a named pipe instead of an anonymous pipe as created by the `pipe` system call?

Comment: What's the benefit of using an anonymous pipe vs a named pipe?  I've never heard that IPCs can't be used to communicate between threads of the same process, which is what I'm doing.  My only problem is dropped records when the pipe buffer fills.

Comment: An anonymous pipe uses less resources than a named pipe. And as both ends are created and returned fully opened with a single system call, you won't have a deadlock situation to worry about (not for that part anyway). But for inter-thread communication consider something that use even *less* resources and don't have to pass through the user-kernel border a couple of time. For example a circular queue implemented all in user-space. There are bound to be lock-less implementations available for you to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three options:

1. FIFOs themselves don't drop messages in nonblocking mode. If your code is dropping messages, fix your code to stop doing that, and then just use nonblocking mode.
2. Open the FIFO in nonblocking mode, then once you get both ends open, use `fcntl` to change it to blocking mode.
3. Use a separate thread or process to open each half of the FIFO.

Comment: I'll try #2.  The two sides are opened in separate threads, but I don't get past the open on the reader side.  As for #1, if a pipe is opened in nonblocking mode and the pipe buffer is full then I believe the write side will drop the record.  That's how nonblocking IPC;s generally work.

Comment: 1. If you do a non-blocking write with the buffer full, it will fail with `EWOULDBLOCK`. If you didn't notice that, then it means you're not checking `write`'s result, which is always a  bug. 2. No they're not. In the code in your question, both ends are opened in the same thread.

Comment: Thanks for your info.  As a minor point, the two C code blocks in my code are called from different threads -- they just appear in the same C file.